# Osascript keycodes for arrow keys

Tags: python, macos, osascript

I'm trying to call osascript in Python to simulate key presses with something like this:

```
cmd = """
    osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "e"'
    """
os.system(cmd)
```

How can I send key presses for the up/down/left/right arrow keys?

Comment: Try doing `os.system(cmd.strip())`

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I was asking. This command works I am just trying to figure out the keycode for the arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

Key codes for the arrow keys:
left - 123
right - 124
down - 125
up - 126

Comment: Correct in principle, but you must formulate like this:  … to key code 125 ( = w/o double quotes!)